# Как пишутся названия танцев?

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, названия

В предложении есть такой список танцев: "греческий танец Каламатьянос, Полька-тройка, Карачаровский вальс, Санта-Барбара, Вирджиния Рил, вальс «Жизнь художника», Вальс-бостон, Танец с цветами".

Я бы написала так:
...греческий танец каламатьянос, полька-тройка, карачаровский вальс, «Санта-Барбара», «Вирджиния Рил», вальс «Жизнь художника», вальс-бостон, танец с цветами.

Но сомневаюсь. Может, нужно по-другому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ваш вариант в основном верен**, то есть нарицательные названия следует отличать от собственных (условных) названий.

Вот только "Карачаровский вальс" я бы написала в кавычках, так как это песня.
["КАРАЧАРОВСКИЙ ВАЛЬС" | salda.ws](https://salda.ws/video.php?id=Q44HzW-lyc8)

Танец с цветами, вероятно, нарицательное название. Для сравнения в балете  Чайковского "Щелкунчик"  есть "Вальс цветов" (также Вальс цветов).